# Decoding Specification '(AA$)' For Write Statement

Tags: io, fortran

I'm confused as the what this write specification is trying to specify. N is an array of single characters. Could someone help me and explain the write format specification below. I saw someone post the exact same question a few days ago but the page is not there anymore.

```
WRITE(*,'(AA$)') N(I),","
```

Comment: Im sorry, but I have never posted on this site before. I have only used it for looking up questions. As I have mentioned in the question, I believe you are referring to the same question I saw before but is no longer there :/

Comment: Well Jerry, I guess a new account is also a way to go ;-) Just don't delete the question...

Answer (score 3):

The dollar sign in a format specifier [suppresses a new line](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007438836/index.html). 
Therefore, the array `N` is written element-wise as a string (`A`) separated by a comma (second string `A`) one a single line.

Note that this syntax is not standard conforming, in modern Fortran you would write the format as

```
WRITE(*,'(2A)', advance='no') N(I),","
```